# Appending questions instead of answering?

Tags: support, comments, answers, not-an-answer

I'm new to Stack Overflow and would like to know what the proper way to find out more about a question before adding an answer.

How do I comment, or find out more about a specific question if more information is required without posting as an answer?

I had an answer removed and I believe this is the reason.

The question:

> I have 2 MP4 videos, I need a flash player or a HTML5 player where I provide these 2 video URLs and they both play as a single video and not 2 separate videos.
>
> Thanks in advance

My answer:

> Do you have the videos or will the be linked remotely?
>
> I'm asking to see if there is a reason why you could not merge the two video files and play it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to post comments. Using answers to post anything but an answer to the original question is inappropriate so such "answers" will be deleted.

I'd suggest you to add some tags you are familiar with to your favorites and answer a few questions. If you post good answers it's extremely easy to get the rep necessary to comment.

Suggesting edits would be another option to get rep, but since you are very new I wouldn't do that - many people suggest rather bad edits in masses just to get rep. Don't be one of them. :)

Comment: I see, so in this case I should get reputation by posting sure-fire answers only until the ability to comment becomes available?

Comment: @user237536 Yes

Comment: Exactly. Posting good questions would give you rep, too (but less rep than good answers) but answering is usually the preferred way to get reputation.

Answer (score 3):

The 'answer' field is for just that - answers. It shouldn't be used to ask for clarification, as that kind of ruins our system.

Instead, comments should be used to ask. You'll need 50 reputation first - which can easily be gained in a day or two by posting high-quality answers to other questions.

Comment: "which can easily be gained in a day or two by posting high-quality answers to other questions" — _if_ the questions that you're qualified to answer are in tags that receive enough traffic that good answers get upvoted.  Edit: actually, accepts would get the job done, too. So, this works _if_ you know about fields which either get enough traffic to upvote answers or in which users who ask questions understand the importance of accepting answers (hopefully both apply).

Answer (score 2):

You should use *comments* to ask clarifying questions.  Answers are strictly for answering the question.  An answer that just asks clarifying questions will be deleted.

You need 50 reputation to be able to comment; until then you'll simply need to focus on questions that you can answer without needing to ask clarifying questions yourself.  Generally the community is quite good about asking for information when needed, so you won't always need to.